# SEM & Identification

Tags: regression, econometrics, structural-equation-modeling

Consider the following demand and supply model:

- Demand equation: $q=a_1p+a_2y+e^d$
- Supply equation: $q=b_1+p+e^s$

The supply equation is identified because $y$ can be used as an instrument for $p$.

The demand equation is **not** identified as it stands.

I am struggling to understand how **linear restrictions on parameters** can be used to identify the demand equation.

For instance:

1) Set $a_2=0.5$ and use $y$ as an instrument in $(q-0.5y)=a_1p+e^d$

2) Set $a_2=-0.5a_1$ and use $y$ as an instrument in $q=a_1(p-0.5y)+e^d$

**Why do 1) and 2) identify the demand equation?**

Thank-you!

Answer (score 1):

In the case of 1), by setting $a_2=0.5$ and taking it over to the RHS one can define a new variable $X=(q-0.5y)$ so that the demand equation can be written:

- $X=a_1p+e^d$

Now $y$ can be used as in instrument for $p$ since:

- $cov(y, p)\neq0$
- $cov(y, e^d)=0$

Therefore the demand equation is identified.

Comment: Does it matter what the sign and value of $a_2$ are set to?